# Center the map on a current location - Titanium

Tags: titanium, mkmapview, currentlocation

I am running my app on simulator and I have 2 issues: 1) default "user current location" is placed on San Francisco. Can I change that without using "region:" and set the delta for long lat? 2)How can I center the map on the current location(I want the current location in the center of the map) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the current location in simulator, that will only work on a device.

Comment: You can set a current location of your choice in the emulator by going to  Emulator''s Settings -> Location -> Single Points  then chose your location -> set location.